# spark group by not getting type, mismatch error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to get this variable `GroupsByP` to have certain type: `GroupsByP` is defined out of db connection select/collect statement which has 3 fields: 2 strings (`p` and `id`) and an int (`order`).

Expected result should be of the form `Map[p,Set[(Id,Order)]]`

```
val GroupsByP = db.pLinkGroups.collect()
  .groupBy(_.p)
  .map(group => group._1 -> (group._2.map(_.Id -> group._2.map(_.Order)).toSet))
```

my desired type for this variable is

```
Map[String, Set[(String, Int)]]
```

but actual is `Map[String, Set[(String, Array[Int])]],`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your question right, this should do it:

```
 val GroupsByP: Map[String, Set[(String, Int)]] = input.collect()
    .groupBy(_.p)
    .map(group => group._1 -> group._2.map(record => (record.Id, record.Order)).toSet)
```

You should be mapping each record into a `(Id, Order)` tuple.

A very similar but perhaps more readable implementation might be:

```
val GroupsByP: Map[String, Set[(String, Int)]] = input.collect()
    .groupBy(_.p)
    .mapValues(_.map(record => (record.Id, record.Order)).toSet)
```

Comment: i think that does it. qq howcome you didn't use the underscore but instead you used record?

Comment: Using underscore as the input argument for anonymous functions like this one means you can only use that unnamed argument _once_ - if you try to use it twice (e.g. `(_.Id, _.Order)`) you're actually creating an anonymous function that takes **two** arguments (with the first underscore referencing the first one, and the second underscore referencing the second). This is obviously not what we need here. In other words - _naming_ the argument (here, I named it `record` - could have used any name that makes sense) is often a *must*. Underscode is short-hand that should be used carefully.